# How can I put a scalebar and a north arrow on the map (ggplot)?

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, graphics

I'm trying to put a scalebar and a north arrow using the package 'ggsn'.
But I recive a error message:

Error: annotation_custom only works with Cartesian coordinates

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In min(data$long) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

2: In max(data$long) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

3: In min(data$lat) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

4: In max(data$lat) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

5: Removed 1374840 rows containing non-finite values (stat_contour).

My code is like this:

```
#loading the map
world <- maps::map("world2", fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE) # world2 is the Pacific centered map with longitude [0,360]

IDs <- sapply(strsplit(world$names, ":"), function(x) x[1])
world <- map2SpatialPolygons(world, IDs=IDs, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

world_map <- fortify(world)

#load the bathymetry 
bat <- marmap::getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = -5.0000, lon2 = -80.0000, lat1 = 14, lat2 = -70.61, keep=T) 

#converting the bathymetry in data.frame
bat2 = marmap::fortify.bathy(bat) 

g <- ggplot(AR, aes(x = lon, y = lat)) + #(old: Longitude #Latitude)
 geom_path(aes(group = sex, col = sex), size = 0.8, alpha = 0.5) +
 geom_map(data = world_map, map=world_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id), fill = "darkgray") +
  geom_contour(data = bat2, 
               aes(x=x, y=y, z=z),
               breaks=c(-200),
               size=c(0.3),
               colour="blue")+
  xlim(extendrange(AR$lon, f = 0.1)) + #(old: Longitude)
  ylim(extendrange(AR$lat, f = 0.1)) + #(old: Latitude)
  coord_map("ortho", orientation = c(-40, -40, 0))

g +
  ggsn::scalebar(world_map, dist = 100,location = "bottomright", transform = TRUE, #Adicione uma barra de escala
                 dist_unit = "km", st.dist = 0.03, st.size = 2, model = 'WGS84') +
  ggsn::north(world_map, scale = .1)
```

Part of my data:

```
structure(list(lon = c(-38.8745, -38.8676, -38.9445, -38.9811, 
-38.9322, -38.9386), lat = c(-14.09437, -14.25664, -14.34518, 
-14.51857, -14.95994, -15.41684), bmode = c(1.396, 1.375, 1.346, 
1.248, 1.074, 1.289), bmode.5 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ID = structure(c(53L, 
53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L), .Label = c("10946.05", "20162.03", 
"21792.03", "21800.03", "21810.03", "24640.03", "24641.05", "24642.03", 
"27258.05", "27259.03", "27261.03", "27261.05", "27261.07", "33000.05", 
"37231.07", "37234.05", "37288.07", "42521.07", "50682.07", "50687.07", 
"60004.07", "81122.09", "81123.09", "81124.09", "81125.09", "81126.09", 
"84497.1", "87632.12", "87759.08", "87761.08", "87762.08", "87763.08", 
"87764.08", "87765.08", "87766.08", "87768.08", "87768.11", "87769.11", 
"87770.08", "87773.08", "87773.1", "87773.11", "87774.09", "87774.11", 
"87775.08", "87776.08", "87776.11", "87777.1", "87778.08", "87783.09", 
"88724.1", "88727.09", "111868.11", "111871.12", "112702.12", 
"112712.12", "112714.12", "120947.12", "121189.12", "121192.12", 
"121196.12", "1211931.12"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("F", "Fc", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    speed = c(0.921691675, 2.990097297, 2.137609076, 3.259383146, 
    8.173674567, 8.413534172), area = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AA", "AM", "AR"), class = "factor"), 
    angulo = c(41.027, -43.41, 29.056, 18.241, -7.125, -4.702
    ), angle_rel = c(0.7160619, -0.7576522, 0.5071251, 0.3183724, 
    -0.1243479, -0.08206201), bat.depth = c(-45L, -397L, -32L, 
    -29L, -21L, -3L), dist = c(5.53015005, 17.94058378, 12.82565446, 
    19.55629887, 49.0420474, 50.48120503), angulo_modulo = c(41.027, 
    43.41, 29.056, 18.241, 7.125, 4.702), curva = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("curva", "reta"), class = "factor")), row.names = 2:7, class = "data.frame")
```

how can i solve this problem?

**####EDIT 1**

I already edited my post and now the object 'world_map' is available.

I'm having trouble using ggspatial.
I loaded all the packages you mentioned and ran the command and was unable to execute the function.
I went to add the package 'ggspatial', but the following message appears:

```
"* installing * source * package 'ggspatial' ...
** package 'ggspatial' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace () for 'sf', details:
  call: get (genname, envir = envir)
  error: object 'group_split' not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggspatial'
* removing 'C: /Users/annel/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/3.5/ggspatial'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages:
  installation of package ‘ggspatial’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘C: \ Users \ annel \ AppData \ Local \ Temp \ RtmpKueyQV \ downloaded_packages’ "
```

When I execute the command you requested I get the message:

```
Error in loadNamespace (name): there is no package called ‘ggspatial’
```

Comment: @IanCampbell 

I edited my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your data (stored in a `data.frame` named `AR`), and trying to match your desired output, here is what I suggest:

```
# Load necessary packages
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(marmap)

# Import AR data

# Transform data points into geographic objects
Sites_geo <- AR %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# Get bathymetry data: please note I zoomed on the area of interest
# to get a more manageable dataset. If you want a larger area,
# you should increase res (e.g. res = 10) in order to get a
# bathy object of a reasonable size
bathy <- getNOAA.bathy(-45, -30, -20, -5, res = 4, keep = TRUE)
# load the bathymetry 
ggbathy <- fortify(bathy)

# Get countries outline
pays <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(
  country = c("Brazil"),
  scale = "large", returnclass = "sf"
)

# Base plot
pl <- ggplot(data = pays) +
  geom_contour(
    data = ggbathy, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z),
    binwidth = 200, color = "grey90", size = 0.3
  ) +
  geom_contour(
    data = ggbathy, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z),
    binwidth = 1000, color = "grey70", size = 0.4
  ) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = Sites_geo, aes(fill = speed), shape = 21) +
  geom_path(data = AR, aes(x = lon, y = lat, group = sex, col = sex)) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-42, -30), ylim = c(-20, -5), expand = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  labs(x = "", y = "", color = "Sex") +
  theme_bw(base_family = "ArcherPro Book")

# Add scale and North arrow
pl +
  ggspatial::annotation_scale(
    location = "tl",
    bar_cols = c("grey60", "white"),
    text_family = "ArcherPro Book"
  ) +
  ggspatial::annotation_north_arrow(
    location = "tl", which_north = "true",
    pad_x = unit(0.4, "in"), pad_y = unit(0.4, "in"),
    style = ggspatial::north_arrow_nautical(
      fill = c("grey40", "white"),
      line_col = "grey20",
      text_family = "ArcherPro Book"
    )
  )
```

This produces the following map:

[image]

The placement of both the scale bar et north arrow are controlled by the `location`, `pad_x` and `pad_y` arguments of the `annotation_scale()` and `annotation_north_arrow()` functions from package `ggspatial`.

Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 13):

I don't know about the `ggsn` package, but if you don't mind using the `ggspatial` package, here is an example of what I understand you're trying to achieve. Since I can't reproduce your code, I've included my own custom dataset and bathymetric data... with some nice font for a better looking final map!

```r
# Load necessary packages
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(sf)
library(marmap)

# Create random data
fake_data <- tibble(
  Latitude = c(45.36, 46.74, 45.35, 45.28, 45.21, 45.92, 43.83, 46.80, 43.70, 43.97),
  Year = factor(c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008)),
  Longitude = c(-2.64, -3.33, -3.22, -2.77, -2.54, -2.69, -1.99, -2.71, -1.68, -2.16),
  Lab = c("960", "950", "956", "962", "961", "768", "865", "848", "866", "860")
)

# Transform data points into geographic objects
Sites_geo <- fake_data %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326)

# Get bathymetry data
bathy <- getNOAA.bathy(-8, 0, 42, 50, res = 1, keep = TRUE)
ggbathy <- fortify(bathy)

# Get countries outline
pays <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(
  country = c("France", "Spain"),
  scale = "large", returnclass = "sf"
)

# Base plot
pl <- ggplot(data = pays) +
  geom_contour(
    data = ggbathy, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z),
    binwidth = 200, color = "grey80", size = 0.3
  ) +
  geom_contour(
    data = ggbathy, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z),
    binwidth = 1000, color = "grey60", size = 0.4
  ) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = Sites_geo, aes(fill = Year), shape = 21) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = fake_data, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, label = Lab),
    force = 3, family = "ArcherPro Book"
  ) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-6, 0), ylim = c(43, 48.5), expand = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "Year") +
  theme_bw(base_family = "ArcherPro Book")

# Add scale and North arrow
pl +
  ggspatial::annotation_scale(
    location = "tr",
    bar_cols = c("grey60", "white"),
    text_family = "ArcherPro Book"
  ) +
  ggspatial::annotation_north_arrow(
    location = "tr", which_north = "true",
    pad_x = unit(0.4, "in"), pad_y = unit(0.4, "in"),
    style = ggspatial::north_arrow_nautical(
      fill = c("grey40", "white"),
      line_col = "grey20",
      text_family = "ArcherPro Book"
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Hello,Thanks for the answer @Benoit. I have another problems now, can you help me with this? I'll edit my post with them.

Comment: @AnneElise if you think this answers your question, you may want to consider to accept it by checking the tick mark next to it - Thanks !

Comment: @AnneElise It seems you tried to install `ggspatial` from source. Have you tried installing  the binary package? `install.packages("ggspatial", type = "binary")`

Comment: @Benoit I'm not getting.
I installed the package as you said, and the north arrow was inserted in my map, but I'm still trying to position it in the right place.
An error still appears for the scale bar.
Is it not possible to help trying to make the map with my data after I have done the editing?
Sorry for the ignorance on the subject. This map is extremely important in my work and I have been trying to work on it for some time.

Comment: @Benoit My data is located at sea, close to the Brazilian coast.

Comment: @Benoit Apologies if this is a stupid question - I'm working on a similar bathymetry data set and trying to replicate the style of this graph, which part of this code fills in the land?

Comment: @LucyWheeler It's the `geom_sf()` line (the shortest line of the script!) that uses the data specified in the very first line of the plot with `ggplot(data = pays)` to plot the countries.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was running into several problems with ggsn, but now both my north arrow and scalebar are done with ggspatial